# How Software Automatic Mouth synthesis speech

Tags: synthesis, speech, formant

Does anyone know by what mechanisms the Software Automatic Mouth (SAM) that is used for text-to-speech on machines including Commodore computers synthesized speech? The manual for the product mentions something regarding target frequency spectra; does this mean all phonemes are generated just using additive synthesis?
In experiments I have done in the past, I have had some success synthesizing vowel sounds using formant synthesis, so I would imagine vowels could be similarly synthesized using additive synthesis, but then by what mechanism are consonant phonemes synthesized?
I have not had much success in finding answers to this from searching online, so I am hoping someone has an explanation of how this product synthesized phonemes.

Comment: The code is available at https://github.com/s-macke/SAM so you can see exactly how it works.

Comment: It looks whoever ported this or wrote the readme and comments on it didn't fully understand how it worked, either. Lots of variables have seemingly meaningless names, and the explanations given appear to just be speculation.

Comment: If you read the background on this it was a conversion from assembly to C

Comment: This sounds a better fit for https://dsp.stackexchange.com/